# Initializer list time member container initialization with array of members

Tags: arrays, templates, c++11, constructor, initialization

I'm attempting to implement class member container initiallization using array of member variables example code:

```
//Pseudo container declaration
class CContainer
{
    template<size_t nSize>
    CContainer(CMember* acArray[nSize]);
};
//class whos members i wanna pass as array to container initialization
class CProblematic
{
    CMember m_1;
    CMember m_2;
    ...
    CMember m_n;
    CContainer m_cContainer;

    //constructor with container initialization
    CProblematic(int parameter)
    : m_1(parameter)
    , m_2(parameter)
    ...
    , m_n(parameter)
    , m_cContainer({&m_1, &m_2, ... , &m_n})
    {}
};
```

I've tried multiple container constructor syntax, but none seem to help, for example i tried to use `CContainer(CMember** apcArray, size_t nSize` and pass it during `CProblematic` construction, but non seem to help when using `{...}` style array creation, maybe someone could point me to my mistake or point toward solution?

I know that the easiest way to solve this is just simply add in constructor body `m_cContainer.Add(&m_1)` for each member, but i'm more interested is there a solution to initiallize this way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a compiler implementing the resolution of [CWG 1591](http://wg21.link/cwg1591), you can do

```
template<size_t nSize>
CContainer(CMember* const (&acArray)[nSize]); // or CMember* (&&acArray)[nSize]
```

And let `nSize` be deduced from the braced-init-list `{&m_1, &m_2, ... , &m_n}`.

Otherwise, to deduce the bound, you can use `std::array` with a helper function template. The following is a simplified version of [`std::experimental::make_array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/make_array):

```
template <class... Ts>
auto make_array(Ts&&... t) -> std::array<std::common_type_t<Ts...>, sizeof...(Ts)>{
    return { std::forward<Ts>(t)... };
}
```

Then do `m_cContainer(make_array(&m_1, &m_2, ... , &m_n))` with a constructor taking a `std::array` like in your answer:

```
template<size_t nSize>
CContainer(std::array<CMember*, nSize>&& aArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

seems that found a solution, if someone stumbles to same problem, here's my solution

```
//problematic constructor 
CProblematic(int parameter)
    : m_1(parameter)
    , m_2(parameter)
    ...
    , m_n(parameter)
    //only drawback, you must specify n by hand
    , m_cContainer(std::array<CMember*, n>{&m_1, &m_2, ... , &m_n})
    {}

//Container constructor
template<size_t nSize>
CContainer(std::array<CMember*, nSize>&& aArray) 
//since we're creating rvalue reference in initialization list
```